# Calling child method from Parent in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know it's a question asked many times on SO but I am still facing a problem don't know how to resolve.

```
import Events from './subComponents/Events'

export default class userHome extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      events:[],
    };
    this.changeView=React.createRef();
  }

  changeViewClick = () =>{
    this.changeView.current.changeDataView();
  };

  render() {
    const {events} = this.state

    return (
      <IconButton onClick={this.changeViewClick}>
        <CardView  />
      </IconButton >
      <IconButton onClick={this.changeViewClick}>
        <TableView /> 
      </IconButton> 
      <Events ref={this.changeView} events={events} />
    );
  }
}

Events Component

export default class Events extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);     
  }

  changeDataView = () => {
    console.log("hi");
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>Hey Child</div>);
  }
}
```

I am getting error as 
**TypeError: _this.changeView.current.changeDataView is not a function**

My reactjs version is **16.6.3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: But solution of duplicate doesn't work

Comment: You have the `changeDataView` as a function outside your child component, not as a method of the class. Move it inside

Comment: sorry I added outside copy paste problem but in actual it's inside...updated it

Comment: Where is the `changeView` coming from in `this.changeView.current.changeDataView();` ? You have not specified anything called changeView  inside the class.

Comment: Try binding changeDataView() in the constructor of Events class.

Comment: @Muljayan I am importing the component does that has effect over anything?

Comment: @Muljayan do you know how to use innerRef?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, have you tried to pass an anonymous function to child component ?

```
onClick={() => this.yourfunction()}
```

It happened, I think, because you called in your child component this props : `this.changeView.current.changeDataView()`

So when you pass that props in the child component you must passed it as an anonymous function to tell React it's a function to execute when the onClick event is triggered.

Let me know if that resolve your problem or if I am wrong

Comment: I did `onClick= {()=>this.changeViewClick}` but then this function is not being called

Comment: You forgot parenthesis at the end of `this.changeViewClick`

Comment: hey if I use like this ref={()=>this.changeView} I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeDataView' of null`

Comment: Try to do this: `{() => this.changeView()}`

Comment: That is the wrong way apart from this changeView is not even a function just a reference

Comment: Do you know how to use innerRef since I found out the problem. It was due to withStyles usage in child component

Comment: Okay my bad, `changeView` is a reference. innerRef is not a standard React property. I didn't use this so now it's all yours.

But maybe with this: `innerRef={x => (this.changeView = x)}` ?

Comment: not working If I remove but If I don't use withStyles where I am exporting my component then it works.....I told you innerRef plays some role here I don't know quite how to use it yet